# Batch script: append data to text file in only one line

Tags: batch-file

I have text file "whitelist.txt" with one line:

```
whitelist_mac="11:11:11:11:11:11 22:22:22:22:22:22 33:33:33:33:33:33"
```

I need a batch script to add a new mac address `44:44:44:44:44:44` to this text in only one line at the end of line with (")

After I run the batch script the modified file should look like this:

```
whitelist_mac="11:11:11:11:11:11 22:22:22:22:22:22 33:33:33:33:33:33 44:44:44:44:44:44"
```

My attempt of a script is this:

```
@echo off
set /p mac=Add new MAC adress to whitelist:
echo whitelist_mac=%mac% >> whitelist.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a FOR loop, the only difficulty is working out how to escape the double quote delimiter

If it's the only line in whitelist.txt, the following works

```
set /p mac=Add new MAC adress to whitelist:
set whitelist=
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2  %%G IN ('type whitelist.txt') DO  (set whitelist=%%G)
echo whitelist_mac^=^"%whitelist% %mac%^">whitelist.txt
```

If there are other lines, then you'll need to do some work with find/findstr (might be worth doing anyway to check for duplicates and check the validity of the provided MAC address)

Comment: Thanks! Only one line. For enter the same MAC adress in two different files, is: echo whitelist_mac^=^"%whitelist% %mac%^">whitelist.txt whitelist2.txt

Comment: No, but you can do echo whitelist_mac^=^"%whitelist% %mac%^">whitelist.txt && copy /y whitelist.txt whitelist2.txt

Comment: set /p mac=Add new MAC adress to whitelist:
set whitelist=
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2  %%G IN ('type mac_ath0.txt') DO  (set whitelist=%%G)
echo nvram set ath0_maclist^=^"%whitelist% %mac%^">mac_ath0.txt 
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2  %%G IN ('type mac_ath1.txt') DO  (set whitelist=%%G)
echo nvram set ath1_maclist^=^"%whitelist% %mac%^">mac_ath1.txt

Comment: required for dd-wrt router setting mac adress whitelist, ssh conection, with putty command line script:  plink.exe -v -ssh 192.168.1.1 -P 22 -l root -pw password -m mac_ath0.txt

Answer (score 0):

How about a powershell script that works on a file in the same folder?  Granted it could be more robust but it works as a simple example. I know you asked for a batch file but I am am dabbling in powershell lately. :-/

```
$NewMac = Read-Host -Prompt 'Add new MAC adress to whitelist'
(get-content .\whitelist.txt) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "`"$", " $NewMac`""}| set-content .\whitelist.txt
```